# how do i insert html markup into a new html page using php?

Tags: php, html

I have a php script that uses a $content variable to write text to a newly created html page that is empty.  my php script works great using regular ascii text.  when i try to insert html markup tags i get an error and script stops working. here is an example.  the html write doesn't work no matter what html tags i use.
 $Content = "echo "";
echo "";
echo "require_once('some.php')";
echo "Hello, today is ";
echo date('l, F jS, Y');
echo "";
echo "";\r\n";

i've tried echoing and not echoing.  do i need to add some type of delimeter or is there a php function i should be using that can get around this problem?

Comment: Please read any PHP tutorial, then read how to ask questions on internet, then read the syntax higlighter tips. Then someone will help you.

Comment: I believe the question asks how to create a new html page (one seperate from the PHP script that creates it) via php. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Making your code a little more presentable...

```
$Content = "echo "";
echo "";
echo "require_once('some.php')";
echo "Hello, today is ";
echo date('l, F jS, Y');
echo "";
echo "";\r\n";
```

Reveals a parse error at the very beginning. `$Content = "echo "";` contains an extra quotation mark (") which the interpreter won't be happy about.
It looks like you're trying to assign all your php code to a variable, which is probably not what you are trying to accomplish.

It seems more likely that you're hoping to...

```
require_once('some.php');
echo "Hello, today is ";
echo date('l, F jS, Y');
echo "\r\n";
echo "<!-- Added by Richard for kicks -->";
```

Try it again and when you visit the script via a browser, go to View->Source and you should see that everything your PHP script echos is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to output information to your HTML page then:

```
echo "<b>This is bold</b> This isn't";
```

Would be the correct format. I see you doing a few things that are obviously broken in the snippets you posted but I have no idea what you're really trying to do.

Why are you putting your content in a variable before outputting it? If you have all your content in $content, the the format to use would be

```
echo $content;
```

Maybe if you posted the actual script someone could be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

First that "php example" shows on google:
http://www.php-scripts.com/php_diary/php_scripts.html